# Move items when empty to the left css html

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I need help, I am making containers with div and inline-block but when the element but I need to move left when the content of the container is empty.This is shown in the runcode

PD::. In the runcode there is an overflow but on my website that does not happen. i'm sorry it's my first time in stackoverflow.com

<

```css
.polaroid1 { 
        width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
       
     }
.kincomposerwoo {
        height: 490px;
     }

@media screen and (min-width: 490px) {
    .polaroid1{
        width: 48%;

    }
    .kincomposerwoo {
        height: 490px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 780px) {
    .polaroid1{
        width: 33%; 
    }
    .kincomposerwoo {
        height: 530px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="kincomposerwoo polaroid1"></div>

<a id="link" href="https://www.merotaco.com/cupon1/"><div class="polaroid1"><img  src=https://www.merotaco.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Cupon-Repertura-Merotaco.com_.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-2648" width="auto" height="auto" /><img style="float: right; margin: 12px 15px 15px 0px;" src="https://www.merotaco.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/612890.png" alt="" width="30" height="30"/><div class="container">REAPERTURA COUPÓN
<br>Expira : 2020-05-11

  </div>
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:empty` selector to check if the content is empty.

```css
.container:empty {
  /* Your CSS goes here */
}
```

Comment: I already provided empty, but it doesn't delete the empty box, I need to replace that empty box with the next one.

Comment: `.container:empty{ display:none; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use css :

```
.kincomposerwoo:empty {
   display:none
}
```

Or you can remove it using Javascript by checking element ( node ) children.

```
const removeWhenEmpty = (element) => {
  for (let el of element) {
    !el.hasChildNodes() && el.remove();
  }
};

const leftElement = document.getElementsByClassName("kincomposerwoo");
removeWhenEmpty(leftElement);
```